# FCK Editor paste from word

Tags: excel, copy

I am using FCKEditor.java 2.6 version but not able to see the option to paste from word. In my case users want to copy tables from Excel and they are not able to do now because I don't have the paste from word option. My understanding is that paste from Word should solve my problem. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure the toolbar to include the `PasteFromWord` button. Selecting the [`toolbar_full` option](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.toolbar_Full) in the config does include that button. BTW: FCKEditor 2.6 is quite outdated; currently, CKEditor for Java 3.6.1 is available.

Comment: I did check this option unfortunately this is available from 3.0 and i am allowed to change the version here at this time. Is there any way to enable this feature in FCKEditor 2.6 version only...? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @jay: i'm not sure, since i only worked with ckeditor's js version, not java. Regarding the javascript version, i'm sure that configuring the toolbar was possible with version < 3.0, so i would expect it working with the java version, too. The 2.6 java version requires fckeditor's 2.6.6 version, and that version already allowed for [customizing the toolbar](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/ToolbarSets). Maybe that config snippet helps.